# Matching the first element when it can occure in different places of the hierarchy?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

So, there is this element that can occur in a lot of elements and I should remove all of them that are within a specific element or its descendants. I can't seem to figure out how to approach it, because the relation is not "fixed". So I provided an example to get my point across:

Input:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <d value="1"></d>
    <b/>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d value="2"></d>
            <d value="1"></d>
        </c>
        <d value="1">
        <d value="2">
    <b/>
</a>
```

Wanted output:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <d value="1"></d>
    <b/>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d value="2"></d>
        </c>
    <b/>
</a>
```

You see the output just has the first element  with value="1" or value="2". Is this even possible with XSL?

Comment: Please explain the logic in words.

Comment: <d> is always a descendant of <a> but not necessarily a child. I want to get rid of all the "double" <d>s in <a>. So if I have 3 <d>-elements with value="1" I just want to first one to stay and if there are many <d> in <a> with different value-attributes I always want the first one with a value that hasn' occured yet to stay and the other ones thrown out. I hope it's now clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a variation on [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="d-by-value" match="d" use="@value" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove duplicate d's -->
<xsl:template match="d[count(. | key('d-by-value', @value)[1]) != 1]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```