# Follow Up on question that got solvend using Muenchian Grouping

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

So, my previous post was this one: 
[Matching the first element when it can occure in different places of the hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039016/matching-the-first-element-when-it-can-occure-in-different-places-of-the-hierarc)

The Muenchian Group seemed to work, but now I have the problem that I have more than one a. For example like this

```
<x>
<a>
    <b>
        <d value="1"></d>
    <b/>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d value="2"></d>
            <d value="1"></d>
        </c>
        <d value="1">
        <d value="2">
    <b/>
</a>
<a>
    <b>
        <d value="3"></d>
    <b/>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d value="1"></d>
            <d value="2"></d>
        </c>
        <d value="1">
        <d value="3">
    <b/>
</a>
</x>
```

You can see, that I have d/@value="1" in a[1] and a[2]. I want to get rid of every d with a value that hasn't occured yet in this particual a. So here I'd want to keep the first  with value="1" and value="2" a[1] and a[2] and the first one with value="3" in a[2] and get rid of all the others.

Resulting in an output like this:

```
<x>
<a>
    <b>
        <d value="1"></d>
    <b/>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d value="2"></d>
        </c>
    <b/>
</a>
<a>
    <b>
        <d value="3"></d>
    <b/>
    <b>
        <c>
            <d value="1"></d>
            <d value="2"></d>
        </c>
    <b/>
</a>
</x>
```

I tried it like that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="d-by-value" match="d" use="@value" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove duplicate d's -->
<xsl:template match="a//d[count(. | key('d-by-value', @value)[1]) != 1]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which results in only the first d/@value="1" in the whole xml to stay (because the overall count in the whole file of course >1 within a different a so I also tried this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="d-by-value" match="d" use="@value" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove duplicate d's -->
<xsl:template match="a//d[count(. | key('d-by-value', @value)[1]) != 1]"/>

 <xsl:template match="d" name="remove-d"/>

    <xsl:template match="paragr">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
            <xsl:for-each select=".//d[count(. | key('d-by-value', @value)[1]) != 1]) = 1]">
                <xsl:call-template name="remove-d"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this seems to get rid of all the d's. Any ideas?

Edit: corrected the xsl:for-each select. Made a copy/paste-mistake and corrected that value-thing, seen in the comment below.

Comment: You have `<d value="1">` occurring twice in the second `a` in your required output? Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: Oh no. I'll edit it. Sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove duplicate values for a given `a` element, then you need to reference to `a` in the key match

```
<xsl:key name="d-by-value" match="d" use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::a), '|', @value)" />
```

Here, `generate-id` will create a unique code for a node in the XML.

You would then need similar logic in the template match when using the key

```
<xsl:template match="a//d[count(. | key('d-by-value', concat(generate-id(ancestor::a), '|', @value))[1]) != 1]"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="d-by-value" match="d" use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::a), '|', @value)" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- remove duplicate d's -->
    <xsl:template match="a//d[count(. | key('d-by-value', concat(generate-id(ancestor::a), '|', @value))[1]) != 1]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: generate-id(). Interesting. Did not know that yet. Does excactly what I want it to do. Thank you.